# Looping over a numpy array and modifing the current value using the previous one

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop

I'm new in python and I have been stuck a whole day on this problem. I know that it's surely a non-pythonic way of coding but I didn't find a vectorial way to do what I want to do here... The problem is that "phi[t]" has to be modified during the loop using the phi[t-1] value. I tried to use temporary variable or to create a copy of phi within the loop but it was unsuccessfull.
It will be great if someone could give me a hint. Thanks !
Here's the code :

```
import math
import numpy
x = numpy.linspace(20, 1200, 20)
R=8.3144621
beta=0.166666
def func(T, n , A, E):
    phi = numpy.zeros(T.shape)
    dphi = numpy.zeros(T.shape)
    for t in range(len(T)):
        dphi[t]=A/beta*(1-phi[t])**n*math.exp(-E/(R*T[t]))
        if t>0:
            phi[t]= phi[t-1]+(T[t]-T[t-1])*dphi[t]
        if phi[t]>1: phi[t]=1
    return dphi
y = func(x, 0.5, 12000, 100000)
```

Comment: Just use `pre` & `cur` variables to store the current & previous elements & modify them accordingly in the loop. Note - You would need **2** variables not just 1, like you tried.

Comment: Are you expecting this output 
     
[  4.88896980e-257   1.73563984e-059   4.33449456e-032   3.46750249e-021
   2.49890102e-015   1.13283831e-011   3.57984706e-009   2.34840793e-007
   5.63679653e-006   6.84168261e-005   5.11955325e-004   2.68472478e-003
   1.07586453e-002   3.50033842e-002   9.65861906e-002   2.33443257e-001
   5.06389364e-001   1.00451930e+000   1.84909959e+000   3.19545191e+000
]

Comment: What's wrong with your code?

Comment: in your current code, (if I'm reading it right), `phi` array doesn't do anything. Since you are only returning `dphi`, the only thing that matters in the loop is the assignment to `dphi[t]`, and in this assignment you are using `phi[t]` which is always 0 since it is not set until AFTER `dphi[t]` assignment.  Do you mean to set `phi[t+1]`?